# Erro de conversão ao definir o valor '' para 'null Converter'. - JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

estou fazendo um programa que cadastra e relaciona um cliente a um cartão de crédito. Estou utilizando o JSF e o PrimeFaces. Não é necessário utilizar o Banco de Dados, então estou armazenando os dados em um ArrayList mesmo.

Basicamente, ao criar um novo cartão eu preciso mostrar todos os clientes cadastrados para que eu possa selecionar para qual cliente será aquele cartão.

Na tela de Cadastro do Cartão, além dos dados pra serem cadastrados, eu coloquei um  onde mostra os resultados de uma ArrayList com o nome de todos os clientes cadastrados. O problema é que quando eu vou tentar criar o cartão com um determinado cliente cadastrado dá esse erro aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei usar alguns converters também, mas sem sucesso e não tenho certeza se esse é o problema. Abaixo estão alguns trechos do meu código.

Classe CartaoBean:

```
public class CartaoBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8764412118399727943L;

private Cartao cartao;

private ArrayList<Cartao> cartoes;

private Boolean mostrarPainel;

private Cliente titular;

public CartaoBean() {
    this.mostrarPainel = true;
    this.cartao = new Cartao();
    this.cartoes = new ArrayList<Cartao>();
}

public void cadastrar() {

    this.cartoes.add(this.cartao);
    this.cartao = new Cartao();

    FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage();
    m.setSummary("Cartão cadastrado com sucesso!");
    m.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
    /**
     * Colocando a mensagem na lista
     */
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, m);
}

public Cartao getCartao() {
    return cartao;
}

public void setCartao(Cartao cartao) {
    this.cartao = cartao;
}

public ArrayList<Cartao> getCartoes() {
    return cartoes;
}

public void setCartoes(ArrayList<Cartao> cartoes) {
    this.cartoes = cartoes;
}

public Boolean getMostrarPainel() {
    return mostrarPainel;
}

public void setMostrarPainel(Boolean mostrarPainel) {
    this.mostrarPainel = mostrarPainel;
}

public Cliente getTitular() {
    return titular;
}

public void setTitular(Cliente titular) {
    this.titular = titular;
}
```

}

Classe Cartão

```
public class Cartao implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -4746760068026694731L;

@NotBlank
private String numero;

@NotNull
private double creditoInicial;

@NotNull
private Cliente titular;

public Cartao() {

}

public Cartao(String numero, double creditoInicial) {

    this.numero = numero;
    this.creditoInicial = creditoInicial;

}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public Cliente getTitular() {
    if (titular == null) titular = new Cliente();
    return titular;
}

public void setTitular(Cliente titular) {
    this.titular = titular;
}


public double getCreditoInicial() {
    return creditoInicial;
}

public void setCreditoInicial(double creditoInicial) {
    this.creditoInicial = creditoInicial;
}
```

}

O xhtml do cadastro

```
<h:body>

<h:form>

    <p:growl globalOnly="true" />

    <p:panel header="Cadastro de Cartão" toggleable="true" closable="true" rendered="#{CartaoBean.cartao.numero}" />

    <h:panelGrid>

    <p:outputLabel for="n1" value="Cliente"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="n1" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cartao}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{clienteBean.clientes}" var="cliente" itemLabel="#{cliente.nome}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>      
    <p:message for="n1" />

    <p:outputLabel for="n2" value="Crédito Inicial"/>
    <p:inputText id="n2" value="#{cartaoBean.cartao.creditoInicial}"/>
    <p:message for="n2" />


    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton update="@form" action="#{cartaoBean.cadastrar}" value="Gerar Cartão de Crédito"/>
    </f:facet>

    </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

você tem que implementar uma classe de converter(conversão) a seguir um exemplo junto ao seu `p:selectOneMenu`

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="n1" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cartao}" converter="ClienteConversor" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{clienteBean.clientes}" var="cliente" itemLabel="#{cliente.nome}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**PessoaConverte**

```
package org.salomao.conversor;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.salomao.model.cliente;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ClienteConversor implements Converter, Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ClienteConversor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                return new ClienteDao().findById(Integer.valueOf(value));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                throw new ConverterException(
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "cliente não valida."));
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if (object != null) {
            return ((Cliente) object).getId();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```